# Initialize uncopyable third-party base class, with pointer to object

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

I'm fighting with Qt. Cannot find out reliable solution for my specific problem.

We have custom `class MyWidget` that must:

- be derived from `QWidget` to override `closeEvent` method
- have fields that must be initialzed in constructor

Problems:

- `QWidget`'s guts initialized with `QUiLoader` from `.ui` file. So I have only `QWidget*` pointer
- `QWidget` is non-copyable.
- `QWidget` has no move constructor

The code (error checking and memory management are omitted for simplicity):

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    bool m_Closed;
public:
    MyWidget(QWidget* qw) : 
        QWidget(*qw), // error: copy constructor is private
        m_Closed(false)
    {}

    bool IsClosed() const { return m_Closed; }

    virtual void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *) override { m_Closed = true; }
};

QFile file("main.ui");
QUiLoader uiLoader;
MyWidget* uiMain = new MyWidget(uiLoader.load(&file));
uiMain->show();
```

Questions:

- How can I workaround this? I feel that solution is very simple.
- Can I use move semantics here somehow?

Note that:

- I cannot make `QWidget` member, as I need to override its method.
- Probably, I can make some `MyWidget::Init()` method, to init those `bool` flag, which must be called after each instantiation. But I find this solution unreliable.
- In the end, I must just have `QWidget`, that I can check if it was closed or not (maybe you know another, simple way)
- I use MSVC 2013 RC and GCC 4.8.1, so C++11 solution would be great

Do not hesitate, I appreciate any suggestions and criticism.

Answer (score 1):

`.ui` files can use custom classes that derive from `QWidget`, so you can use your class in the Designer - even without writing any Designer plugins (it won't be shown). Right-click on a widget and select "Promote".

You need to create your own derived version of `QUiLoader`, and provide an implementation of the factory method `QUiLoader::createWidget` that can create your widgets. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37797117/1329652) for a complete example.

Then you put your initialization code in the derived widget.