# QUiLoader: requirements for loading .ui file with custom widgets?

Tags: c++, qt, uiloader

I've created a UI using Qt5-Designer which I load at runtime by calling

```
QUiLoader().load(qfile_object, this);
```

Works like charm but now I've promoted some `QLabel` elements to a widget class `MyQLabel` with is derived from `QLabel`.

When I now try to load the UI I get a warning for each promoted widget:

```
"QFormBuilder was unable to create a custom widget of the class 'MyQLabel'; defaulting to base class 'QLabel'."
```

The class looks like this:

```
class MyQLabel : public QLabel {
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    MyQLabel(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QLabel(parent) {}
};
```

It's been auto-`moc`'ed and linked against my executable.

I have the feeling that somehow I have to tell `QUiLoader` about my class before trying to use it but I don't know how..

Do I have to create a plugin for this? Is there a way to reproduce, what to `QUiLoader` does to examine it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your own derived version of `QUiLoader`, and provide an implementation of the factory method `QUiLoader::createWidget` that can create your widgets.

You could factor this out into a plugin that gets loaded by the `QUiLoader`. It would have to implement a [`QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesignercustomwidgetinterface.html) instance. See the [Custom Widget Plugin Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-customwidgetplugin-example.html) for a complete example of a plugin.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/uiloader-custom-37775472
#include <QtUiTools>
#include <QtWidgets>

const char uiData[] =
    "<ui version=\"4.0\"><class>Widget</class><widget class=\"MyWidget\" name=\"Widget\">\n"
        "<property name=\"windowTitle\" ><string>Widget</string></property>\n"
        "</widget><pixmapfunction></pixmapfunction><resources/><connections/>\n"
    "</ui>";

class MyWidget : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    bool m_closed = false;
public:
    MyWidget(QWidget* parent = 0) : QLabel("This is MyWidget", parent) {}
    bool isClosed() const { return m_closed; }
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE { m_closed = true; }
};

class MyUiLoader : public QUiLoader {
public:
    MyUiLoader(QObject * parent = 0) : QUiLoader(parent) {}
    QWidget * createWidget(const QString & className, QWidget * parent = 0,
                           const QString & name = QString()) {
        if (className == "MyWidget") {
            MyWidget * w = new MyWidget(parent);
            w->setObjectName(name);
            return w;
        }
        return QUiLoader::createWidget(className, parent, name);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QBuffer buf;
    buf.setData(uiData, sizeof(uiData));
    MyUiLoader uiLoader;
    auto uiMain = qobject_cast<MyWidget*>(uiLoader.load(&buf));
    uiMain->show();
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: I think your missing an override in createWidget?