# QUiLoader widget not showing if loaded in derived QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, qwidget

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) {
    file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    QWidget *w = loader.load(&file);
//    MyWidget *w = new MyWidget(loader.load(&file));
    vLayout.addWidget(w);
    file.close();        
    vLayout.addWidget(&bt);
}
```

[image]

The code above produces the image above. But I would like to do something with the widget just loaded, that's why I derived `MyWidget` from `QWidget`. And there seems to be the problem.

If I replace `QWidget` by `MyWidget` then it doesn't show there anymore. The code below produces the image below.

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) {
    file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
//    QWidget *w = loader.load(&file);
    MyWidget *w = new MyWidget(loader.load(&file));
    vLayout.addWidget(w);
    file.close();        
    vLayout.addWidget(&bt);
}
```

[image]

Where `MyWidget`:

```
// mywidget.h
#include <QWidget>

class MyWidget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
};

// mywidget.cpp
#include "mywidget.h"    
#include <QDebug>

MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) {
    qDebug() << "do something here";
}
```

Question 1: Why the widget (group box) isn't showing there? How to make it appear?

Ok, question 1 completed thanks to @KubaOber. Now I would like to access the widgets inside `untitled.ui`, I tried:

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) {
    foreach (QLabel *label, parent->findChildren<QLabel*>())
        if(label->objectName().contains("Value"))
            qDebug() << "label" << label;

}
```

But it returns nothing. Instead, passing a parent in `loader.load(&file, vLayoutWidget))` makes the `untitled.ui` widgets available but also craps the contents of `vLayoutWidget`. I guess the question is what should be passed in as parent in the `loader.load())`?

Comment: Ideally you'd create a self-contained test case in the style of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37797117/1329652).

Comment: Please post a new question instead of editing into an old one.

Comment: Which old one are you referring to?

Comment: You can't iterate anything in `MyWidget`'s constructor, because it has no children yet at that point. And again, please absolutely post **complete** test cases. I'm can't but assume how the rest of your code looks. You're also making your life much harder by not having a simple piece of code to experiment on without messing up your main project. Learn how to quickly create test projects using Qt Creator. You can use [my simple qmake project template](https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/qtcreator-templates) to aid in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you use the loader doesn't mean "load a `MyWidget` using `QUiLoader`:

```
MyWidget *w = new MyWidget(loader.load(&file));
```

What you're doing above is initializing a `MyWidget` that has whatever the loader has loaded as a *parent*. And then you're promptly reparenting `w` by adding it to a layout, effectively discarding whatever the loader has loaded.

You need to tell the loader what parent to add the widgets it has loaded to, of course noting that `MyWidget` doesn't need to be dynamically allocated:

```
auto w = new MyWidget;
loader.load(&file, w);
```

Here's how it might look when put together:

```
class Widget : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  QVBoxLayout m_layout{this};
  MyWidget m_myWidget;
  QVBoxLayout m_myLayout{&m_myWidget};
public:
  explicit Widget(QIODevice * source, QWidget * parent = nullptr) : 
    QWidget{parent}
  {
    auto loaded = QUiLoader{}.load(source, &m_myWidget);
    m_layout.addWidget(&m_myWidget);
    m_myLayout.addWidget(loaded);
  }
};
```

If your ui file's top-level widget is a `MyWidget`, then you'll need to let the loader know how to instantiate it - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37797117/1329652) for details. And then you would write it as follows:

```
class Widget : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  QVBoxLayout m_layout{this};
  MyWidget * m_myWidget;
public:
  explicit Widget(QWidget * loaded, QWidget * parent = nullptr) : 
    QWidget{parent},
    m_myWidget{qobject_cast<MyWidget*>(loaded)}
  {
    m_layout.addWidget(m_myWidget);
  }
};

...
MyUiLoader loader{}
auto loaded = loader.load(...);
Widget widget{loaded};
...
```